# Using Flask and WTForms how can i have a table where some columns are inputs?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm struggling to see how this is done, and the documentation doesn't seem to help much.

I need to generate a table, the row size will be variable, but not dynamic (i know how much rows i need before generating the page).

For the sake of simplicity lets imagine a page where you grade n exams with an integer.

i tried this:

**the form.**

```
class InputInteger(Form):
    grade = IntegerField('Grade')
```

**the view**

```
@decorator..
def grade():
    form = InputInteger()
    names = student_list

    return render_template("grade.html", form=form, names=names)
```

**the template**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
    {% for name in names %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{form.grade}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But how do i read back the inputed values?
How do i distinguish who's grade that belongs too?

Am fairly confused, i've read about FieldList(FormField(IntegerField)), but isn't that just one field with a list of integers?
What about the Table Widget, do i need that?

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking at this now, the OP was correct to think about `FieldList`s and `FormField`s. Here is a solution:

forms.py:

```
class GradeForm(FlaskForm):
    student = IntegerField('Student ID')
    grade = IntegerField('Grade')
    delete = BooleanField('Delete')

class GradeFormSet(FlaskForm):
    gradeset = FieldList(FormField(GradeForm), min_entries=0)
```

view.py:

```
def grade():
    # create a dict of student IDs and their initial grades (or None for now)
    init_merits = [dict(student=s.id, grade=None) for s in myStudentTable.query.all()]
    gradeform = GradeFormSet(gradeset=init_merits)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ...
        # meritforms.data['gradeset'] contains a list of dictionary values for further processing
        # check 'delete' == True to handle deletion of that student from your table
        ...
    return render_template('template.html', form=gradeform)
```

Template:

```
<table>
{% for merit in form.gradeset %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ merit.placing(readonly=true) }} {{ merit.csrf_token }} {{ merit.hidden_tag() }}</td>
        <td>{{ merit.grade }}</td>
        <td>{{ merit.delete }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<input type="submit" name="finish" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right. Put your table inside a html form and catch in a function where you can retrieve your input fields.

**Here is an example:**

```
<form action="/grade">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
        {% for name in names %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td><input id='{{name}}' value='{{ form.grade }}'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**And your Flask function:**

```
@app.route('/grade', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def grade():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      return 'Form posted.'
```

When you post your form to your function, you can access your input field by this way: `request.form['inputfieldname']` and then you do your stuff. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: but how can i grade several names at the same time?
Sorry i'm not following how request.form['grade'] will get me the list of grades input and how do i tell to what name they were graded

Comment: If you generate inputs by using a for loop make sure to give them a unique name each of theme. Then when you will post the change by submitting your form, your function will receive your form and all its input data. If you still don't understand what i mean, will post a complete solution for you.