# Flask WTForms FormField/FieldList prepopulate + submit

Tags: flask

For the sake of example, I'm making a cookbook app. Looking through this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827997/using-flask-and-wtforms-how-can-i-have-a-table-where-some-columns-are-inputs) here, I've managed to get a little of the way, but having difficulty conceiving how to prepopulate the form and submit the data.

Honestly [the documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/?highlight=formfield#wtforms.fields.FormField) is a little short on detail and lacking in examples, and most of the examples I've seen on the web are [either](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqumX6deRR8) lacking in interaction with the database, or just a little too complex.

For the sake of simplicity, say the data structure is 1 x Recipe -> Many Recipe Steps.

All I want to do is to be able to prepopulate the form with data from the db matching the recipe (I currently have the correct amount of steps displaying but no prepopulation), then when the form is updated, submit the amendments to the db. The SO answer I linked above, leaves the population/submission stuff out of this, and it's a little beyond Flask basics for me.

#### View.py

```
@app.route('/recipe/<int:recipe_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def recipe(recipe_id):
    recipe_form = RecipeForm()
    init_recipe_steps = [dict(recipestep=s.id, recipe_id=recipe_id) for s in RecipeSteps.query.filter_by(recipestep=recipe)]
    recipe_step_form = RecipeStepFormSet(stepset=init_recipe_steps)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # how do I get the info from the dictionary to show here? 
        recipe_step_form.recipe_step_name.data = recipe_step_form.recipe_step_name
        recipe_step_form.recipe_step_temp.data = recipe_step_form.recipe_step_temp
```

#### Forms.py

```
class RecipeStepForm(FlaskForm):
    recipe_step_name = StringField('Recipe Profile Name')
    recipe_step_temp = DecimalField('Step Temp', places=1)

class RecipeStepFormSet(FlaskForm):
    stepset = FieldList(FormField(RecipeStepForm), min_entries=0)
```

#### Template

```
            {% for step in recipe_step_form.stepset %}
                {{ step.recipe_step_name }}
                {{ step.recipe_step_temp }}
            {% endfor %}
```

#### Prepopulating the form Answer

```
init_recipe_steps = [dict(recipestep=s.id, recipe_id=recipe_id, recipe_step_name=s.name, recipe_step_temp=s.step_temp) for s in RecipeSteps.query.filter_by(recipestep=recipe)]
```

Turns out I was fairly close, but the dictionary wasn't defined properly so the data wasn't coming through. See above for the solution.

Comment: @CodeMantle you posted this originally - don't suppose you're able to chime in here? Having a bit of a headache trying to get my head around the use of the dictionary in both field population and submitting it to the database.

Comment: So far I've figured out how to prepopulate the form - the fields need defining in dictionary. See answer above.